# Changing Url in Yii2

Tags: php, url, yii2

I want to change this url:

`http://www.themusicartists.com/index.php/Artist/Reviews-11`

**Into:**

`http://www.themusicartists.com/index.php/Reviews-11`

I want to change only this **URL**:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => true,
         'rules' => [
            '<id>' => 'posts/view',
            'Artist/<id>' => 'music-categories/view',
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: Add new rule for this 'Artist/Reviews-11' => 'Reviews-11',

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment looks to be a direct map instance. Like `about` changed to `about-us` kind of thing. If you want this to be dynamic I would think it should be (untested):

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => true,
     'rules' => [
        '<id>' => 'posts/view',
        'Reviews-<id>' => 'music-categories/view',
    ]
],
```